# Not able to configure Reliance Netconnect USB dongle with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, usb

I've a Netconnect USB dongle which is I am not able to use with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am noob

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800 (HSPA modem)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I've used wvdial which says

```
kp-15:~$ sudo wvdial
[sudo] password for user: 
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

I've also used gnome-ppp and tried all combination of 'eevice' and 'type' to let the GUI detect the modem. But GUI tool was not able to detect the connected modem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may not install any dialer. Follow the steps below:

1. Go to Network Management --> Mobile Broadband
2. If the driver name is not visible then click on "Add" and follow instructions till you reach the tab where you are asked to enter login credentials
3. Enter numer as "#777", user id and password are the 10 digit phone number given to you.

Cheers!

Comment: tried this, didn't worked. I don't really know why but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

**This is HowTo using wvdial instead of NetworkManager**

plug in the dongle and in terminal run

```
$ sudo wvdialconf
```

this identifies the modem device file and various modem properties like baude rate for u and updates `/etc/wvdial.conf`

Now

```
$ sudo vi /etc/wvdial.conf
```

and give username and password which are both ur modem phone number and destination phone no `#777` to dial

```
Username = 9393209369
Password = 9393209369
Phone = #777
```

Now dial

```
$ wvdial
```

Thats it. *Make sure u got sufficient balance else recharge it.

Comment: didn't work, executing the cli 'wvdialconf' results in error "Sorry no modem is was detected!". but lsusb shows the device as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then the fault is with modem drivers. Linux community might not yet updated itself with ur modem driver. Anyway U should try updating ubuntu preferably to 13.04. If u got drivers cd with linux drivers try installing them but u should have luck not breaking ModemManager. If u break ModemManager u got to re-install NetworkManager.

Comment: no I don't have the driver CD, Also 1. I've tried with 13.04 same problem. 2. The dongle is pretty old purchased in 2010. 3. Able to use it without any problem till date with Any version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue. I use a reliance netconnect dongle. What I did was, access a windows machine, change the dongle setting to hybrid, reboot into ubuntu and run `sudo wvdialconf`

wvdial detected the modem and generated the conf. Then I modified the conf with the username and password. Then run `wvdial`.

That worked.